# Filter table with multiple values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code here which is a sample of table data, where we can filter per column, now i want to filter in a status field with multiple value, example: what if i want to print data which are the completed and ongoing and suspended, then this data should be the only data to be printed, what should i do?, Please help!

```js
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
    $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function () {
    var $i = $filters.filter(function () {
        return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
        len = $i.length;

    if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

    var cls = '.' + $i.map(function () {
        return this.className
    }).get().join(',.');

    $rows.hide().filter(function () {
        return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function () {
            var content = this.textContent,
                inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

            return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

        }).length === len;
    }).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="filter_table">
  Input here to Search <br>
                      <input type='text' class='Program' id='Program' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Program" />
                      <input type='text' class='Year' id='Year' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Year" />
                      <input type='text' class='Province' id='Province' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Province" />
                      <input type='text' class='LGU' id='LGU' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="LGU" />
                      <input type='text' class='Barangay' id='Barangay' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Barangay" />
                      <input type='text' class='Project' id='Project' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Project" />
                      <input type='text' class='Allocation' id='Allocation' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Allocation" />
                      <input type='text' class='Status' id='Status' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Status" />
</div>

<table border='1' class="table table-hover" id='products'>
            <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th width="10px">Program
                      </th>
                      <th width="10px">Year
                      </th>
                      <th width="20px">Province
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Municipality/LGU
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Barangay
                      </th>
                      <th  width="30px">Project
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Allocation
                      </th>
                      <th  width="20px">Status
                      </th>
                      <th  width="5px">PA%
                      </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2012
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province1
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px" class='Project'>Project1
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>200000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Status'>completed
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">100%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2013
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province2
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px" class='Project'>Project2
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>500000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Status'>ongoing
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">50%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program3
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2014
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province3
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px" class='Project'>Project3
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>6000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Status'>suspended
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program4
                      </td>
                      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2016
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province4
                      </td>
                      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="30px" class='Project'>Project4
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Allocation'>1000000
                      </td>
                      <td  width="20px" class='Status'>cancelled
                      </td>
                      <td  width="5px">0%
                      </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do here is to use a delimiter for keywords in your `status` filter and read the value as an `array` after splitting over this separator.

Here's a code that uses space as a delimiter, and filters the status colum upon multiple values:

```
let val = this.value;
$rows.hide().filter(function() {
  return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
    var content = this.textContent,
      inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

    let vals = val.split(" ").map(function(v) {
      return v.toLowerCase();
    });
    return vals.some(function(v) {
      return content.indexOf(v) > -1;
    });
  }).length === len;
}).show();
```

**Note:**

This will be used only with the `status` column, I made a whole working demo snippet here.

**Demo:**

```js
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
  $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function() {
  var $i = $filters.filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
    len = $i.length;

  if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

  var cls = '.' + $i.map(function() {
    return this.className
  }).get().join(',.');

  if (this.id != 'Status') {
    $rows.hide().filter(function() {
      return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
        var content = this.textContent,
          inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

        return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

      }).length === len;
    }).show();
  } else {
    let val = this.value;
    $rows.hide().filter(function() {
      return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
        var content = this.textContent,
          inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

        let vals = val.split(" ").map(function(v) {
          return v.toLowerCase();
        });
        return vals.some(function(v) {
          return content.indexOf(v) > -1;
        });
      }).length === len;
    }).show();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="filter_table">
  Input here to Search <br>
  <input type='text' class='Program' id='Program' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Program" />
  <input type='text' class='Year' id='Year' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Year" />
  <input type='text' class='Province' id='Province' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Province" />
  <input type='text' class='LGU' id='LGU' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="LGU" />
  <input type='text' class='Barangay' id='Barangay' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Barangay" />
  <input type='text' class='Project' id='Project' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Project" />
  <input type='text' class='Allocation' id='Allocation' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Allocation" />
  <input type='text' class='Status' id='Status' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Status" />
</div>

<table border='1' class="table table-hover" id='products'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="10px">Program
      </th>
      <th width="10px">Year
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Province
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Municipality/LGU
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Barangay
      </th>
      <th width="30px">Project
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Allocation
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Status
      </th>
      <th width="5px">PA%
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2012
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay1
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>200000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>completed
      </td>
      <td width="5px">100%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2013
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay2
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>500000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>ongoing
      </td>
      <td width="5px">50%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program3
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2014
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay3
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>6000000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>suspended
      </td>
      <td width="5px">0%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program4
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2016
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay4
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>1000000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>cancelled
      </td>
      <td width="5px">0%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

## Edit:

This is a snippet using a dropdown for the `Status`filter:

```js
var $rows = $('tbody > tr'),
  $filters = $('#filter_table input');

$filters.on("keyup", function() {
  var $i = $filters.filter(function() {
      return $.trim(this.value).length > 0;
    }),
    len = $i.length;

  if (len === 0) return $rows.show();

  var cls = '.' + $i.map(function() {
    return this.className
  }).get().join(',.');

  $rows.hide().filter(function() {
    return $('td', this).filter(cls).filter(function() {
      var content = this.textContent,
        inputVal = $i.filter('.' + this.className).val();

      return content.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal.toLowerCase()) > -1;

    }).length === len;
  }).show();
});

$("#Status").on("change", function() {

  let val = $(this).val();
  
  $rows.hide().filter(function() {
    return $('td', this).filter(function() {
      var content = this.textContent;
      
      let vals = val.map(function(v) {
        return v.toLowerCase();
      });
      return vals.some(function(v) {
        return content.indexOf(v) > -1;
      });
    }).length >0;
  }).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="filter_table">
  Input here to Search <br>
  <input type='text' class='Program' id='Program' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Program" />
  <input type='text' class='Year' id='Year' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Year" />
  <input type='text' class='Province' id='Province' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Province" />
  <input type='text' class='LGU' id='LGU' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="LGU" />
  <input type='text' class='Barangay' id='Barangay' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Barangay" />
  <input type='text' class='Project' id='Project' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Project" />
  <input type='text' class='Allocation' id='Allocation' style="width: 100px;" placeholder="Allocation" />
  <select multiple class="Status" id="Status" style="width: 100px;">
    <option value="completed">completed</option>
    <option value="ongoing">ongoing</option>
    <option value="suspended">suspended</option>
    <option value="cancelled">cancelled</option>
  </select>
</div>

<table border='1' class="table table-hover" id='products'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="10px">Program
      </th>
      <th width="10px">Year
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Province
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Municipality/LGU
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Barangay
      </th>
      <th width="30px">Project
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Allocation
      </th>
      <th width="20px">Status
      </th>
      <th width="5px">PA%
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2012
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay1
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project1
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>200000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>completed
      </td>
      <td width="5px">100%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program1
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2013
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay2
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project2
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>500000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>ongoing
      </td>
      <td width="5px">50%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program3
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2014
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay3
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project3
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>6000000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>suspended
      </td>
      <td width="5px">0%
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td width="10px" class='Program'>Program4
      </td>
      <td width="10px" class='Year'>2016
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Province'>Province4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='LGU'>Municipality/LGU4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Barangay'>Barangay4
      </td>
      <td width="30px" class='Project'>Project4
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Allocation'>1000000
      </td>
      <td width="20px" class='Status'>cancelled
      </td>
      <td width="5px">0%
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I hope it matches your needs.

Comment: Yeah, this is it!, can we make a drop down or check box?, it is possible?

Comment: @Darsil Yes of course we can, I am editing the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much!